# Ensuring HttpClient can be used safely as a singleton

Tags: c#

There has been talk recently of how we should be handling the lifetime of the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

This article http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html says that we should use it as a singleton, but we need to be careful about ensuring the connections are properly closed otherwise DNS changes won't be honoured.

I came up with the following message handler which can be injected in to an `HttpClient` to take care of setting the connection lease for each distinct scheme + host combination.

```
public class ServicePointManagingMessageHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Uri, ServicePoint> _uriCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Uri, ServicePoint>();
    private readonly int _oneMinuteInSeconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalSeconds;

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.RequestUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
        {
            var baseUri = new Uri($"{request.RequestUri.Scheme}://{request.RequestUri.Host}");

            _uriCache.AddOrUpdate(baseUri, uri =>
            {
                var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
                sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = _oneMinuteInSeconds;

                return sp;
            }, (uri, point) => point);
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new ServicePointManagingMessageHandler());
```

I am wondering if the concept of intercepting the URI's as they come in to the `HttpClient` will allow the `HttpClient` to safely be used as a singleton without any of the issues listed in that article.

This gets around needing to know all hostnames that you might connect to at startup by intercepting calls - if people agree with this approach then it seems like it should become the accepted way to use the `HttpClient` for standard cases.

Comment: Hm, you are asking a question, yet there is not a single question mark to be found :). It would be good to state what specifically you'd like to get reviewed

Comment: @ChrisWue obviously the entire thing.

Comment: @ChrisWue I thought the question is always the same: how can I make my code better/prittier/faster/s.o.l.i.d-er etc... ;-)

Comment: Haven't been active here for a while, but people were always encouraged to be more specific in terms of being a bit more specific what areas of review they like. I suppose this isn't a lot of code.

Comment: Ha good point. Looks like I left a bit off the end explaining why I've written this - let me revise

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Can you include the bit that helps people better answer my original question without the code change please?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few things:

1. You have already named the variable `_oneMinuteInSeconds` - I'd say you don't gain much by initializing it via a `TimeSpan` the way you do it. Just saying `_oneMinuteInSeconds = 60` would be good enough since it's quite clear what the 60 stands for.
2. Actually, according to MSDN the [`ConnectionLeaseTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionleasetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) is set in milliseconds as such your code is of by a factor of 1000 regarding the timeout (why the framework designers have not consistently used `TimeSpan` everywhere is a bit of a mystery to me).

Comment: Cheers - I'll fix those up. Do you agree with the general concept of putting this logic here? The article mentioned running this code for each hostname that you think you will connect to - I am trying to intercept the calls so you don't have to do that

Comment: @JamesHulse: Hm, sorry but I don't know enough about the internals of the `HttpClient` to assess that.